# How to filter vuetify datatable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to filter a table on chip click which has two values from an array. But when I click on one chip I am getting the error that my namOfFunction is not a function.

I have an availableTime array which is filled from my backend, this array has two fields called startTime and endTime. My chip displays these two fields. Now if I click on one chip I want to filter my table according to the start and endtime inside that chip. I tried doing this with a computed function but no luck, before that I am filtering with a select box which works. But here the method is not recognized as a function.

could someone look at my code tell me what my mistake is?

html:

```
<v-data-table
            v-model="selected"
            :headers="headers"
            :items="filterByDate"
            item-key="voter"
            single-select
            show-select
            class="elevation-1"
            v-on:select="pushSelected()"
          >
            <template v-slot:top>
              <v-col cols="3">
              <v-select
                  :items="availableTimes"
                  item-text="date"
                  @select="filterByDate"
                  v-model="selectedDate"
                  ></v-select>
              </v-col>
              <v-col cols="12">
                <v-chip-group
                    v-model="selection"
                    active-class="deep-purple--text text--accent-4"
                    mandatory
                >
                  <v-chip
                      v-for="(time, i) in dateTimeArray"
                      :key="time"
                      :value="time"
                      @click="filterByTime(time)"
                  >
                    {{ time.startTime +" : "+ time.endTime }}
                  </v-chip>
                </v-chip-group>
              </v-col>
            </template>
          </v-data-table>
```

Script:

```
computed: {
    filterByDate: function () {
      this.getTimesFilteredByDate()
      return this.availableTimes.filter((availableTime) => {
        return availableTime.date.match(this.selectedDate)
      });
    },
    filterByTime: function (time){
      return this.availableTimes.filter((availableTime)=>{
        return availableTime.startTime.match(time.startTime)
        && availableTime.endTime.match(time.endTime)
      })
    }
```

I just put those parts which I think are important if there is anything else needed please feel free to tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed if I put it outside of computed and inside methods the method is called out normally but the table is still not filtered according to the values inside of the chip